# Are MimeTypes lowercase / case insensitive?

Tags: mime-types, rfc

We have some code that processes messages based on mimetypes, which requires matching them. A cursory glance suggests are all lower-case, which leads one to wonder if:

- they are so by convention, or
- is that part of the spec? (a search of RFC 2045/2046 for upper/lower case etc. did not return any hits)

So, can the case insensitive compare be omitted for the *tiny* performance boost ?

Comment: `application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12` is an example of a MIME type often written with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MIME types are case insensitive. They are lowercase by convention only.

[RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) says: "The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive." If you have a MIME type of `text/plain` that's a type of `text` and a subtype of `plain`. So, per the spec, these are not case sensitive.

As [Cromax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024692/cromax) notes in a comment, MIME type **parameter values** may be case-sensitive. See the comment or the spec for details. But if you're matching only the mime type, subtype, or parameter **names**, they are case insensitive. Anecdotally, most people work with mime type and maybe subtype, and those are case insensitive.

Comment: It is worth to add this quote from above mentioned RFC: *The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive.  For
   example, TEXT, Text, and TeXt are all equivalent top-level media
   types.  **Parameter values are normally case sensitive**, but sometimes
   are interpreted in a case-insensitive fashion, depending on the
   intended use.  (For example, multipart boundaries are case-sensitive,
   but the "access-type" parameter for message/External-body is not
   case-sensitive.)*.